# BITMAPDATA issue on 64 bit and 32 bit C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am developing an application using c++
I am facing a problem when trying to capture screen. then edit some of its pixels
and save the image

My code works absolutely fine when when i select the platform as Win32
but as soon as i change the platform from Win32 to x64, the code fails

It start giving access violation when trying to access the pixels
I checked that under both platforms, size of int is 4 bytes and imageData.Stride is coming as -5528
when i do (row*stride/4 + col) i get same value on both platforms

imageData.getPixelFormat() returns 139273 which is PixelFormat32bppRGB
under both platforms

I am posting the code below
please help me out, i have done lot of google, but nothing helps

The access violation error comes at this line
UINT curColor = pixels[row * iStride / 4 + col];
when row value is >0

```
void BitmapToJpg(HBITMAP hbmpImage, int width, int height)
{
    p_bmp = Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hbmpImage, NULL);


    CLSID pngClsid;
    int result = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &pngClsid);
    if (result != -1)
        std::cout << "Encoder succeeded" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Encoder failed" << std::endl;



//***************************Testing Lockbits********************************//
// successfull results and position is also correct
BitmapData imageData;
Rect rect(0, 0, width, height);

p_bmp->LockBits(
    &rect,
    ImageLockModeWrite,
    p_bmp->GetPixelFormat(),
    //PixelFormat24bppRGB,
    &imageData);

cout << p_bmp->GetPixelFormat();

UINT* pixels;
pixels = (UINT*)imageData.Scan0;
int iStride = imageData.Stride;

int x = sizeof(int);
byte red = 0;
byte green = 0;
byte blue = 255;
byte alpha = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < width; ++col)
    {
        ///Some code to get color

        UINT curColor = pixels[row * iStride / 4 + col];
        int b = curColor & 0xff;
        int g = (curColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
        int r = (curColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        int a = (curColor & 0xff000000) >> 24;
        //result_pixels[col][row] = RGB(r, g, b);
        if (b>15 && b < 25 && g<5 && r>250)
        {
            //Red found

            //Code to change color, generate ARGB from provided RGB values
            UINT32 rgb = (alpha << 24) + (red << 16) + (green << 8) + (blue);

             curColor = rgb;
             b = curColor & 0xff;
             g = (curColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
             r = (curColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;
             a = (curColor & 0xff000000) >> 24;


            cout << "Red found" << endl;
            pixels[row * iStride / 4 + col]=rgb;
        }

    }
}

p_bmp->UnlockBits(&imageData);
//*****************************Till Here*************************************//

p_bmp->Save(L"screen.jpg", &pngClsid, NULL);
delete p_bmp;
}
```

Comment: and what is `BitmapData`?

Comment: class Gdiplus::BitmapData

Comment: If iStride is negative, you are bound - pun intended - to get errors.  You need to take the absolute value of iStride to 'walk' the array.  iStride being negative simply means the image is 'upside-down', not that the pointer you get is near the end of the array.

Comment: I had taken that into account, iStride is -ve on both platforms, still it works on 32 bit and dont on 64 bit

Comment: What does `LockBits` return?

Comment: LockBits returned data is stored in pointer &imageData

Comment: Not really, it returns `Gdiplus::Status` value that should be inspected before accessing `imageData`.

Comment: The code ought to always fail when the stride is negative.  But an AVE is not a guarantee.  This is otherwise a crappy implementation detail, normally the scanlines of a bitmap are stored upside-down, the last row of pixels is the first row of data.  But sometimes they are not and the first byte in the data is the upper-left pixel of the bitmap.  And then the stride is negative.  I personally haven't run into buggers like that very often, only a 8bpp image.